# null result in bulk api 2

Tags: rest, bulk-api

I followed the [insert walkthrough](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/walkthrough_upload_data.htm) in the bulk api 2 docs.  But when I checked the results I got 0 records processed and an unhelpful status of

> null:InternalServerError : null

I toyed with the input file but could not resolve the error.

Comment: If possible, consider submitting a bug report to Salesforce (create a case). You typically should not be getting InternalServerError messages, and also they shouldn't be producing null values. I don't know if they'll get it fixed, but it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it was the input file.  I mistakenly thought one field was a Date but it was a DateTime.

I post this here in case someone else gets the unhelpful error message.  Try stripping down your input to the bare minimum and build it back up.  Sadly for me the bare minimum included the Date (Time).  So if the bare minimum still fails, double-check your data types.